# Algorithmically pick which rule to apply?

Tags: prolog

Let say I have the following rules :

```
?- assert(test(5,2) :- true).
true.

?- assert(test(5,3) :- true).
true.

?- assert(test(5,4) :- true).
true.

?- test(5,K).
K = 2 ;
K = 3 ;
K = 4.

?- findall(K,test(5,K), L).
L = [2, 3, 4].
```

I can find all the solutions. But I want something different.

In this scenario "5" is the condition and the second term K is a SCORE.

I want to find all the rules that match "5", but be able to pick which one to execute,
based on the SCORE. Currently the max score "4".

Ideally I want to get the list of all the matching rules and pick randomly one with higher score.
This means I need to get back the rules as a structure, so that I can pick algorithmically one of them.

How can I do that ?

---

I want to simulate Production system (IF-THEN rules), where every rule have a score. The head of the rule should play the IF part.
The THEN part should not be executed until rule is selected based on the score !

Comment: How do you plan to know what the score for a given rule is with a given first argument without querying the rule? Do these rules have side effects you're trying to avoid? And what do you mean "pick randomly one with higher score". The "higher score" evaluation already negates the randomness. Perhaps you can illustrate with a concrete example?

Comment: it will be rule in the final version, not fact

Comment: Every single goal in a horn clause functions as an if, so you can say `goal(Input, outputScore), outputScore > 4, call(Functor, outputScore).` and I know there's a math.random function somewhere, allowing you to create a list with options to be picked based on their position, via a randomly generated number. EDIT: [Generate a random number function in SWI](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=random/3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood your problem correctly, the starting point for you would be using [clause/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=clause/2) predicate in conjunction with `findall` to get all possible scores, then find maximum and call your `test/2` predicate with its value:

```
findall(Score, clause(test(5, Score), Body), Scores),
max_member(MaxScore, Scores),
test(5, MaxScore).
```

PS: I am assuming that you use Swi-Prolog.

Comment: that with clause() was clever, exactly what i wanted not to evaluate it immediately.